# Fail to translate a polar point by a vector

Tags: tikz-pgf

My objective is to draw the following trivial diagram (just for an illustration purpose).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,0) circle (1) (2,0) circle (1);
    \draw (60:1) ++(-2,0) -- (120:1) ++(2,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I got the following.

[image]

Why cannot `(120:1) ++(2,0)` be considered as a point `(120:1)` translated 2 unit to the right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way it is written now, it is drawing to `(120:1)` and then moving the pen (without drawing) 2 units to the right.

One way to solve it is to use the `calc` library and group the shift into one coordinate:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,0) circle (1) (2,0) circle (1);
    \draw (60:1) ++(-2,0) -- ($(120:1)+(2,0)$); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another way, without using an extra library, is to switch to a path and define coordinates at the start and end. Then draw the line between the coordinates:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,0) circle (1) (2,0) circle (1);
    \path (60:1) ++(-2,0) coordinate (start) -- (120:1) ++(2,0) coordinate (end);
    \draw (start) -- (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output in both cases is the same:

[image]

Comment: In the second case you don't need `--` in the `\path …;` where you define the coordinates.

Comment: @Manuel, I know that, I just changed only the command to keep the explanation simple. It has no effect on the output.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be applying a `shift` to each coordinate. It's possible to use `xshift`, `yshift` and `shift`. This last one needs to write external braces around the shifting value `{(x,y)}` as is shown in next code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,0) circle (1) (2,0) circle (1);
    \draw ([xshift=-2cm]60:1) -- ([shift={(2cm,0)}]120:1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]