# How to Put Tikz label of Length

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am very new to Tikz. Now I want to get this done...[image]

THere must be a simple way to do so...

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? The easiest way is to draw it with the software of your choice and then include it with `\includegraphics{}`.

Comment: Related Question: [Dimensioning of a technical drawing in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz).

Answer (score 5):

Next time, please show us what you've tried as it is much easier to help that way. I have no idea what you are stuck on so it is hard to be very helpful, and I have no idea what your general setup is, which might make my solution useless to you.

I used loops because I don't like typing repetitive stuff. If you don't mind, you can avoid them. The commented line labels the nodes which makes it easier to see how the figure is constructed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (a) -| ++(32mm,37mm) coordinate [midway] (b) coordinate (c) -| ++(-18mm,-23mm) coordinate [midway] (d) coordinate (e) -| coordinate [midway] (f) cycle ;
%   \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d,e,f} \node at (\i) {\i};
  \foreach \i/\j/\k/\m/\n/\p in {a/b/32/0/-5/below,b/c/37/5/0/right,c/d/18/0/5/above,a/f/14/-5/0/left,f/e/14/0/5/above} \draw [<->] ([xshift=\m pt, yshift=\n pt]\i) -- ([xshift=\m pt, yshift=\n pt]\j) node [midway, \p] {\k~cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: looped shape]

Comment: Thanks so much for prompt reply. I am not famillar with Loops yet, so my set up is like I create coordinates (0,0), (0,3.2), (0,1.4) etc and \draw()--()--cycle; and then calculate each midpoints and put label e.g. (0,.7)node[left]{$14cm$}; 

Then it would become cumbersome to calculate coordinates of arrows to draw. I intended to use Shift but not sure how to use yet. I will learn from your example. THanks.

Answer (score 5):

Although the answer of cfr is nice, short but a bit complex to understand, I wrote an answer which is probably easier to understand at the beginning, regarding your comment on the answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % set up coordinates for an easy use
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (3.2,0);
  \coordinate (c) at (3.2,3.7);
  \coordinate (d) at ({3.2-1.8},3.7);
  \coordinate (e) at (1.4,1.4);
  \coordinate (f) at (0,1.4);

  \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- cycle;

  \draw[<->] ([yshift=-0.3cm]a) -- ([yshift=-0.3cm]b) node[midway, below]{\SI{32}{\centi\metre}};
  \draw[<->] ([xshift=+0.3cm]b) -- ([xshift=+0.3cm]c) node[midway, right]{\SI{37}{\centi\metre}};
  \draw[<->] ([yshift=+0.3cm]c) -- ([yshift=+0.3cm]d) node[midway, above]{\SI{18}{\centi\metre}};
  \draw[<->] ([yshift=+0.3cm]e) -- ([yshift=+0.3cm]f) node[midway, above]{\SI{14}{\centi\metre}};
  \draw[<->] ([xshift=-0.3cm]f) -- ([xshift=-0.3cm]a) node[midway, left]{\SI{14}{\centi\metre}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The basic idea is to use coordinates so if you change some values, you do not have to alter them in all places you use. The next step is, that you draw the scheme.

To place labels have a look at other answers, for example at the one mentioned from Peter Grill in the comments of your answer. You often do not calculate the midpoints, there is the way to use the anchor *midway*. This way it would be placed exactly in the middle. From this starting point you shift the anchor to *left*, *below* or what you need.

I do not want to use too many coordinates, so I use an offset to the already defined ones for the arrow placement as explained for example [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209392/).

For the text the siunitx package is used for the correct space between the value and the unit.

Comment: This looks useful. As I said in my answer, I just had no clear idea of the OP's starting point. This is great as a response to the comment. And, also, your typesetting of the units is superior to mine, as you say.